# Реализовать обратный отсчет с помощью setInterval или setTimeout

Tags: javascript

у меня есть функция, которая запускает игру. Я хочу, чтобы во время того, как пользователь нажмет на нужную кнопку реализовать обратный отчет, который будет отображаться на самой кнопке. А потом, когда отчет закончится, установить значение кнопки равной "Старт!".

```
function startGame(e) {
    /* other code... */
    for (let i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        setInterval(() => {
            startBtn.value = i;
        }, 1000);
    }
    startBtn.value = "Старт!";
    inputText.focus();
    startTime = Date.now();
}
```

Вместо этого у меня выполняется сначала код, расположенный ниже setInterval, а потом сам setInterval. Помогите исправить ошибку. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: это не ошибка...setInterval будёт запущен через секунду, две и тд.

Comment: @GGO, Мне надо, чтобы сначала выполнился setInterval, а потом код после него, а не наоборот.

Comment: а готовый [вариант](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp) не подходит?

Comment: Хм, а здесь? -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227537

Comment: @Igor We need more countdowns %)

Comment: @Igor вы не понимаете, это другое...

Comment: @РусланМамедов Мне не нравятся комментарии, которые начинаются с хамского захода "вы не понимаете". Никакой разницы между этими вопросами нет.

Comment: @Igor Не сердитесь, это всего лишь популярная шутка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function startGame(e) {
  const timerFunc = (count) => {
    if (!count) {
      this.value = "Старт!";
      this.disabled = false;
      // код после setInterval
    } else {
      this.value = "Countdown - " + count;
      setTimeout(timerFunc, 1000, --count);
    }
  }
  
  this.disabled = true;
  timerFunc(3);
}
```

```html
<input value="Старт!" type="button" onclick="startGame.call(this,event)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа такого?

```js
function startGame(startBtn) {    
    let counter = 3;    
    
    for (let i = counter, j = 0; i >= 0; i--) {        
        setTimeout(() => {     
            startBtn.value = (i === 0) ? 'Старт' : i;
        }, 1000 * j++);
    }    
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="YO" onclick="startGame(this);">
```

Comment: Если несколько раз кликнут на кнопку - будет проблема)

Comment: Ну тут идея. Понятно, что надо делать disable (или по-другому убирать возможность клика, например через css)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sleep = (time = 1000) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));

let is_start = false;

async function startGame() {
    if (is_start) return;
    is_start = true;

    for (let i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        startBtn.innerText = i;
        await sleep();
    }
    
    startBtn.innerText = 'Конец';
    is_start = false;
}

startBtn.onclick = startGame;
```

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

button {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="startBtn">Старт</button>
```